# Ottoman Turkish (Arabic letters)

Tags: fonts, languages, arabic

Is it possible to write Ottoman Turkish with TeX, LaTeX, or ArabTeX?

Comment: Could someone please change the Tag to {Ottoman},{Turkish},{Arabtex} if possible. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to create new tags and I had to take the closest named arabic.

Comment: How is Ottoman Turkish different than Arabic, script or otherwise?

Comment: @Yossi: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_Turkish_language

Comment: I don't see a good reason for creating a tag for every possible language in the world. The {arabic} tag should cover all languages written in {arabic} script (this is still far more specific than {cjk} and {indic} which are the other two language-ralated tags already in use).

Comment: @caramdir thats fine. as long as these tags help others find and solve questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using XeTeX or LuaTeX, with Unicode input and a font with proper support (e.g. Scheherazade), things should be as simple as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}

\newfontfamily\ottoman[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}
\begin{RTL}
\ottoman
لسان عثمانی
\end{RTL}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error if using xetex doc.tex: This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./xetexottoman.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}

Comment: use `xelatex` instead, I'd suggest also upgrading to texlive 2010.

Answer (score 7):

Using LaTeX you can use [arabtex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/arabic/arabtex/) with the `setfarsi` option. You will need to use transliterations for the input (much like pinyin in Chinese). Here is a minimal:

```
\documentstyle[12pt,arabtex]{article}
\parindent=0pt 
\begin{document}
\null \vskip -2cm
\setfarsi \novocalize \Large
%
\begin{arabtext}
a b c d e f g h  \\
0123456789\\
donald knuth pasha\\
\end{arabtext}
%
\testoutput
\end{document}
```

Would appreciate it if you can provide a good paragraph for testing, as I don't speak the language (know a bit of Turkish and Arabic). The output has its own beauty though.

[image]

Comment: I will make sure to add an image of a turkish/ottoman text.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on “how much” text you need in that language, you can set small pieces of text just setting:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\A}{Geeza Pro} %or any other font
```

Now you can insert thus:

```
{\A السلام عليكم}
```

And compile with xelatex or luatex.

Comment: This assumes you are compiling with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.  You should make this clear in the answer.