# How to write Persian/Arabic text in a LaTeX document which is mainly written in English?

Tags: languages, bidi

Actually, I want to add some sentences in Arabic script inside my PhD thesis. Will it be possible just by adding some `\usepackage` statement in the preamble or need more than this? This is a bit tricky requirement in the sense that English script is written from left to right but the Persian/Arabic text is written other way around! I don't know how LaTeX deals with such requirements. Any idea?

Comment: Please have a look at this it includes an example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12406/963.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89428/inserting-some-arabic-script-in-an-english-article

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `ArabTeX` package:

http://ctan.org/tex-archive/language/arabtex

It uses a transliteration system so that you can write Arabic or Farsi using latin letters (hence you won't have directional problems and you can use any text editor).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this but it changes the whole document into Arabic text. How to avoid this from happening? How to make sure that only desired sentences appear in Arabic text?

Comment: Use `\begin{RLtext}salAm\end{RLtext}` to get a whole paragraph, or `This is a greeting: \<salAm>` in running text.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The Persian that ArabTeX provides is useless!