# Inserting some Arabic script in an English article

Tags: xetex, languages, arabic, bidi, persian

Until now I was using XePersian package to typeset Persian articles, now I want insert some Persian word in an English document, what is minimum code to do that without using XePersian package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tahoma}


\begin{document}
book
کتاب
% rendered as ک ت ا ب but should be rendered کتاب

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should try the Polyglossia package.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov Thanks, can you please give me a minimum example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very simple. I do it like this:

```
\usepackage{bidi}% this should be the last package to load.
\newfontfamily\Kayhan[Script=Arabic]{XB Kayhan}% for example
\newenvironment{Farsi}%more human readable - other stuff can be added as well
{\begin{RTL}}
{\end{RTL}}
```

Then just write farsi like this:

```
This is an english paragraph with some 
\begin{Farsi}\Kayhan
نوشته فارسی
\end{Farsi}
that is added.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\faFont[Script=Arabic]{Yas}   
\usepackage{bidi}
\newenvironment{Fa}{\begin{RTL}\faFont}{\end{RTL}}
\newcommand{\fa}[1]{{\faFont\RL{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Fa}
پاراگراف فارسی
\end{Fa}
This is a Persian word: \fa{سیب}. It means apple.
\end{document}
```

Use `fa` for word level and `Fa` for paragraph level of Persian contents.

Answer (score 0):

Use XePersian: 
http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian/xepersian.pdf

```
1 \documentclass{minimal}
2 \usepackage{xepersian}
3 \usepackage{enumerate}
4 \settextfont{XB Niloofar}
5 \begin{document}
ﺍﯾﻦ ﻓﻘﻂ ﯾﮏ ﺁﺯﻣﺎﯾﺶ ﺍﺳﺖ 6
7 \end{document}
```

Comment: Some Persian in English document not vice versa!!

Comment: Ya, That what I meant! It is not hard to align stuff to left or right ...