# how to insert arabic glyphs in pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, cyrillic, arabic

I'm trying to create an English document using `pdflatex` and want to insert a few cyrillic and arabic glyphs.

something like

```
the letter Я is cyrillic, whereas ش is arabic
```

I tried to follow advice found [Inserting some Arabic script in an English article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89428/inserting-some-arabic-script-in-an-english-article), but it seems that `xetex` and `pdflatex` are mutually exclusive.

my feeble attempts until now look like:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,USenglish,arabic]{babel}
\begin{document}
the letter Я is Cyrillic, whereas ﺵ is arabic
\end{document}
```

any hints how to achieve this?

Comment: You'll be much better of using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. The unicode support in pdflatex is limited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to properly mark the parts where different scripts are used; this works, for instance:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,arabic,USenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}
the letter \foreignlanguage{russian}{Я} is Cyrillic,
whereas \foreignlanguage{arabic}{و} is arabic

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that works great! (though i'm having troubles now with the pdf-TOC, included images, and my multi-glyph sentence being on a separate page; but this might be related to the .sty i have to use)

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot. A small hint for arabic, if you are writing more than one letter use `\textRL{السلام عليكم}` to show the text correctly right to left :)

Comment: @iamaziz Good point about `\foreignlanguage{arabic}` not being enough when you have multiple letters; however `\textRL` is deprecated because when you load both Arabic and Farsi it uses whichever language was loaded last. Instead, the documentation says you should use `\AR` for Arabic and `\FR` for Farsi (Persian). (Discovered this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368201/48).)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Great point, and straightforward solution thanks! I didn't actually realize that since I was loading one language only.