# Arabic text in python code in listings at latex

Tags: listings, python

I'm writing python code in my latex file, but it contain some Arabic texts when I write it using **listings** in python the Arabic words don't appear!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
 if(len(tokens[c5]) >= 3):
    if (tokens[c5][0] == 'ان' and
    pos_tags[c5][1] == 'verb' and
    tokens[c5][1] != 'يكون' and
    tokens[c5][2] == 'النظام' or 
    tokens[c5][2] == 'التطبيق' or
    tokens[c5][2] == 'البرنامج'):
        NF_CF[i] += 53.33
        NF_Score[c5] +=1

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a known issue for `listings` to display Unicode characters correctly. There are some workarounds like `literate` (more info see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378606/234654)).

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry It seems like I need to declare all the characters. it is too difficult to declare all Arabic letters!!

Comment: 28 characters seem to be a lot of work indeed. But maybe the package `minted` is more capable of doing more complicated syntax highlighting (as well as Unicode support). The downside is that you have to enable shell escape.

Comment: Are you using pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX? The answer would be very different in these cases.

Comment: @user202729 pdfLaTeX

Comment: First use Babel [pdftex - how to insert arabic glyphs in pdflatex - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95678/how-to-insert-arabic-glyphs-in-pdflatex) , then use LaTeX escape. Unfortunately that way you lose automatic syntax highlighting/emphasis etc. and have to apply them manually (textcolor, textbf)